# Creating a new excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone please help me with the following code:

```
Dim NewOutputFile As Workbook
Set NewOutputFile = Workbooks.Add(FileName & ".xls")
```

where `FileName = "C:\Documents and Settings\me\My Documents\file.xls"`

I want to create a new workbook dynamically and then add new tabs:

```
NewOutputFile.Sheets.Add ("New tab")
```

EDIT when I say "workbook" I mean a new excel file

Comment: What problems are you having?  If `FileName = "C:\Documents and Settings\me\My Documents\file.xls"`, then `Workbooks.Add(FileName & ".xls")` will be `Workbooks.Add("C:\Documents and Settings\me\My Documents\file.xls.xls") `

Comment: I had to change the code to set NewFile = Workbooks.add and then NewFile.saveas Filename:=FileName. However, I now get problems with the Sheets.Add call

Comment: *What* problems?  If you're getting an error, what's the error message?  If the behavior isn't working as expected, what isn't working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NewOutputFile.Sheets.Add().Name= "New tab"
```

Or if you want to add a Worksheet as the last Worksheet:

```
NewOutputFile.Sheets.Add(After:=NewOutputFile.Sheets(NewOutputFile.Sheets.Count)).Name = "New tab"
```