# Splitting Excel into separate folders and then having file within each folder. Both Folder and File named the same as Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I used code from post [split Excel workbooks into separate file and then save in separate folders based on unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132603/split-excel-workbooks-into-separate-file-and-then-save-in-separate-folders-based) as seen below. It runs and halfway thru I get a Save Failed error always on the same worksheet named "NRI Pediatrics." I removed that sheet and it then runs. Wondering if I can at least have code to skip a sheet and go onto the next.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SplitFile()
Const dstTopLevelPath       As String = "N:\Reports\__Gaps in Care Monthly Reports\2020\9.30.2020\_Pediatrics"
Dim dstFolder               As String
Dim dstFilename             As String
Dim dstWB                   As Workbook
Dim dstWS                   As Worksheet
Dim srcWB                   As Workbook
Dim srcWS                   As Worksheet
Dim Practice                    As String

'Ensure the destination path exists
If Dir(dstTopLevelPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox dstTopLevelPath & " doesn't exist - please create it before running this macro"
    End
End If

Set srcWB = ActiveWorkbook

For Each srcWS In srcWB.Worksheets
    'Get the Agency name
    
    Practice = srcWS.Name

    'Create the destination path
    dstFolder = dstTopLevelPath & "\" & Practice
    'Create the destination file name
    '(use this line if you want the new workbooks to have a name equal to the agency name)
    dstFilename = dstFolder & "\" & Practice & ".xlsx"

    '(use this line if you want the new workbooks to have the same name as your existing workbook)
    '(Note: If your existing workbook is called "xyz.xlsm", the new workbooks will have a ".xlsm"
    ' extension, even though there won't be any macros in them.)
    'dstFilename = dstFolder & "\" & srcWB.Name

    '(use this line if you want the new workbooks to have a fixed name)
    'dstFilename = dstFolder & "\data.xlsx"

    'Create a new workbook
    Set dstWB = Workbooks.Add

    'Copy the current sheet to the new workbook
    srcWS.Copy Before:=dstWB.Sheets(1)

    'Get rid of any sheets automatically created in the new workbook ("Sheet1", "Sheet2", etc)
    For Each dstWS In dstWB.Worksheets
        If dstWS.Name <> srcWS.Name Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            dstWS.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next

    'Ensure the new location exists, and create it if it doesn't
    If Dir(dstFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir dstFolder
    End If

    'Save the new workbook to the required location
    dstWB.SaveAs dstFilename

    'Close the new workbook
    dstWB.Close

Next

MsgBox "Finished"
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add an `If` statement below this line of code `For Each srcWS In srcWB.Worksheets'  like, e.g. `If srcWS.Name <> "NRI Pediatrics" Then`

Comment: thanks. anything more generic, as when I deleted that sheet it did it again on another one (albeit the last sheet, so it wasn't as big a deal)

Comment: no '.' Sorry that was just my punctuation.

Comment: I just ran a test with two sheets (BEK Quack & NRI Pediactrics) and your code worked just fine. One thing you should check for is that the file doesn't already exist in the destination directory.

Comment: yes, it is weird. the others open and save very quickly and NRI gets hung up. Then when I try and manually save it, it says it is corrupt, yet it's just like all the other worksheets.